# How to git-rebase from the point where previous rebase stopped?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase

I have an experimental branch to which I'd like to regularly merge progress made on master.

In other words, I do `git rebase master` on my branch, fix conflicts etc., continue my work on the branch, then some day I want to bring more changes from master. If I simply do `git rebase master` again, it starts from the same point when the branch was created, which means I should go through all the conflicts and other complications again.

Is there an easy way of saying 'rebase from the point where last rebase stopped' without specifying commit IDs?

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can avoid having to re-do conflicts by using [`git rerere`](http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html). It can be enabled by running `git config --global rerere.enabled true`.